# ObjectDisposedException - Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, wpf, objectdisposedexception, hp-trim

I am having some issues with my WPF Windows C# application.  Whenever the application is closed, it throws a `System.ObjectDisposedException`. The problem seems to only occur when it is compiled in 32-bit. The 64-bit build runs fine without throwing any exception.

From the exception message, it says cannot access a disposed object but it doesn't seem to tell what object is causing the issue - How do I find out the object that has been disposed?

> Exception:Thrown: "Cannot access a disposed object." (System.ObjectDisposedException)
>   A System.ObjectDisposedException was thrown: "Cannot access a disposed object."
>   Time: 1/19/2016 5:16:28 PM
>   Thread:[1552]
>
> Exception Info: System.ObjectDisposedException
>   Stack:
>      at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(System.String)
>      at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32, UInt16, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType, System.String[], Byte[], System.String)
>      at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(System.String, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType, Int32, Int16, Byte[])
>      at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(System.String, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType)
>      at HP.HPTRIM.SDK.TrimApplicationBase.UnregisterStackTrace(System.Object, Int32)
>      at HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database.internal_Dispose()
>      at HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database.Finalize()

Comment: Is `HP.HPTRIM.SDK` your code?

Comment: It is a .dll file that my code is using

Comment: Either you disposed the HP database earlier or it's a buggy 3rd party SDK.  Is there more to the stack trace?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HP TRIM specifically, but a Google search suggests that there are different HP TRIM libraries for compiling against 32-bit versus 64-bit.  When compiling in 32-bit are you switching to 32-bit libraries?

Comment: @cokeman19 I'd say he would be because otherwise you get the dreaded  Bad Image Format exception.

Comment: Yes, I switch to the 32 bit libraries when compiling in 32 bit and the stack trace above is all I have got in Visual Studio.  Just found the object name that is causing the problem under the Locals panel: [System.ObjectDisposedException] {"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'EventLogInternal'."}  Would the problem be coming from the event log instead or it is irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this is too late to be useful but I stumbled on this because I've recently encountered a very similar (identical?) issue when using the HP Records Manager SDK (v8.3 in my case).  I believe I've identified the cause.

There was a bug in my own code (an executable using the HP .Net SDK to connect to HPRM) where I hadn't called `Dispose()` on one of its SDK objects).

It seems that when the `GC` comes along to clean up as the executable exits, HP decides it wants to write a message to the Windows Application Event Log, pointing out that a developer forgot to `.Dispose()` of the object properly.  For whatever reason, though, there seems to also be a bug in the HP SDK whereby, at this time, it'd disposed of its internal system for writing to the Event Log.  (Sometimes it works for me, sometimes not.  Probably a race condition somewhere in the SDK.)

The consequence was that after the end of my code, the .Net Framework jumped up and screamed about the HP SDK's attempt to use a disposed object for writing to the event log.

The immediate fix for me was to fix my own code. Once I'd disposed of all the objects I was meant to (specifically a Database connection I'd created), the chain of events wasn't kicked off.  Really, though, the HP code also seems to be buggy.

Comment: Thanks.  This was exactly what I had done to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. An explicit TRIMDB.Dispose() solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last line of the stack trace you will see that the problem is being caused in the Dispose() of an `HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database` object.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as much of an answer as it is too long to render usefully in a comment.

I spent some time in `ILSpy` looking at the `EventLog` class.  That innermost method in the exception, `EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite`, is designed to explicitly throw an `ObjectDisposedException` when one of its internal flags is set.  (And though it's always possible that the `ObjectDisposedException` you're receiving is not specifically from this line, it is interesting to note.)

```
private void OpenForWrite(string currentMachineName)
{
    if (this.boolFlags[256])
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(base.GetType().Name);
    ...
}
```

The flag it's checking only gets set when that `EventLog` instance's `Dispose` method has been called, meaning the `EventLog` instance is actively disposing.  Since this is something out of your control, this may be a bug in HP TRIM's `HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database`'s `IDisposable` implementation, since one of the two HP methods listed in the exception would hold the reference to the `EventLog` instance.

It's also worth noting that it's possible this exception is triggered because the `HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database` instance is not being disposed properly (assuming its `IDisposable`) during application close and is just being allowed to fall out of scope.  As a test, you might try disposing your `HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database` instance sometime that's not during application close and see if you can replicate the error.

What any of this would have to do with the bitness, I can't say.